# Get name of public key used to connect

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, public-key

I created a shell script that asks the connected user a question and after that it give him the prompt. The shell posts the question to a database for logging. The problem is that our developers are using a shared account, but each user has it's private key. Is there any way to read with the shell script (bash) what public key the connected user has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similar cuestion on [Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/can-i-find-out-which-ssh-key-was-used-to-access-an-account). With this in mind, you could grep the latest entry in your logs for the connecting IP:

```
REMOTE_IP=${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}
grep -B1 ${REMOTE_IP} /var/log/auth.log
```

Supposing you are using debian, sshd  logs go to `auth.log`. If using an RH like distro they would be in `secure.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You could raise the sshd logging level to VERBOSE by setting the LogLevel directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
LogLevel DEBUG
```

this causes sshd to log the following for each connection

```
Aug 17 12:16:20 centos sshd[9587]: Connection from 192.168.254.200 port 58107
Aug 17 12:16:20 centos sshd[9587]: Found matching RSA key: 54:d2:06:cf:85:ac:89:f6:3c:a8:73:c7:a1:30:c2:8b
Aug 17 12:16:20 centos sshd[9588]: Postponed publickey for user from 192.168.254.200 port 58107 ssh2
Aug 17 12:16:20 centos sshd[9587]: Found matching RSA key: 54:d2:06:cf:85:ac:89:f6:3c:a8:73:c7:a1:30:c2:8b
Aug 17 12:16:20 centos sshd[9587]: Accepted publickey for user from 192.168.254.200 port 58107 ssh2
Aug 17 12:16:20 centos sshd[9587]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
```

The environment variable SSH_CONNECTION contains information oh the current connection

```
192.168.254.200   58107          192.168.254.89   22 
<sourece IP>      <source port>  <destination IP> <destination port>
```

With a little bit of scripting it should be possible to pull the two together.